# Escape Character in C++ Macro Function?

Tags: c++, boost, variadic-functions

I am working on `c++` variadic argument. I run into some problems in the expansion of macro function `va_arg`. The code I have is the following

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, last_known_param);

...

auto input = va_arg(args, boost::multi_array < float, 3 >);
```

What I am trying to do is to get the input as a three-dimensional array. However, it seems that the compiler is unable to take `boost::multi_array < float, 3 >` as a whole and complains to me that I give him three arguments rather than two. One possible workaround is

```
typedef boost::multi_array < float, 3 > boost_multi_array_float_3;
auto input = va_arg(args, boost_multi_array_float_3);
```

But I am just wondering whether there are any other solutions in addition to this (such as an escape character)?

Comment: In this case specifically, you can use a variadic template. C-style variadic functions rely on a lot of trust, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Last I checked, you cannot pass non-POD types to C-style variadic functions either, and I doubt `boost::multi_array` is a POD.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I will look into these.